# External hard disk(HHD) showing irregular capacities and partitions

Tags: mac, time-machine, disk-utility, partition, hdd

I tried to partition my external hard disk on Mac using disk utility.

First I have Erased newly added `2TB HHD` with "`Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`" with "`GUID Partition` ".

After that I have created three partition

```
PC - Exfat - 500 GB

Time Machine - APFS (Encrypted) -- 500GB

MAC - APFS -- 1TB
```

I was trying to use "Time Machine" partition as backup but it was failing and giving error so I have erased HDD again with "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" with "GUID Partition Map" but It got messed up.

[image]

[image]

Though I just have 2TB capacity it showing up to 3.5TB in total and irregular partitions ?

I have tried Erase few more time completely but given partitions are not going away.

How to restore to its original state no partition with "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" having GUID Partitions Map ?

Answer (score 0):

You can restore your drive to its original state by following these steps:

***WARNING***: THIS WILL REMOVE ALL YOUR DATA FROM THE HARD DRIVE

1. Open Disk Utility
2. Click "View" in the menu bar
3. Click "Show All Devices"
4. Select your hard drive from the devices list(It will have a name like "2TB Hard Drive")
5. Click "Erase"

Comment: Had tried already !!

Comment: Ok, do you have a windows computer?  I have helped someone who had the same problem before.  Check my answer on this page: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/407763/cannot-reformat-or-unmount-external-that-was-used-for-time-machine/407765?noredirect=1#comment568082_407765

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Unmount all partitions on the disk. The disk is the external drive. The disk identifier of `disk2` came from an image the OP posted in the question.

   ```
   diskutil unmountdisk disk2
   ```
2. Write zeros to the Master Boot Record (MBR) and both GUID partition table headers on the disk. In other words, write zeros to the first, second and last sectors on the disk. The GUID partition table entries are unchanged.

   ```
   sudo gpt destroy disk2
   ```
3. Write zeros to the MBR and all sectors occupied by the primary and secondary GUID partition tables. Write a protected MBR partition table and signature of `0xAA55` to the MBR. Initialize new primary and secondary GUID partition table headers. Add a small `EFI` partition containing a FAT32 formatted volume with the label `EFI` to the disk. Add a `Apple_HFS` partition containing a `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` formatted volume with the label `MyExternal` to the disk. This partition covers almost all the remaining unallocated space on the disk.

   ```
   diskutil erasedisk jhfs+ MyExternal gpt disk2
   ```